# How do I convert the items of an LI into a json object using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json

If I have a list like the following:

```
<ul class="nameList">
    <li value="1">Bob</li>
    <li value="2">Frank</li>
    <li value="3">Sally</li>
</ul>
```

How can I convert that into a json object like so:

> [{"id":"1","title":"Bob"},
>   {"id":"2","title":"Frank"},
>   {"id":"3","title":"Frank"}]

I need to get that data into that format so I can then pass pass it in a $.post() call back to my php server.

Can someone tell me how to get the items from that list and convert them into the above json using jQuery?

Answer (score 10):

jQuery actually has something built-in for building the array: [map()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map#arraycallback)

```
var items = $('.nameList').find('li').map(function() {
  var item = { };

  item.id = this.value;
  item.title = $(this).text();

  return item;
});
```

That will build an array of objects matching the JSON structure you're after.  Then, to JSON serialize that, use JSON.stringify which is built into newer browsers and available for older ones by including [json2.js](http://www.json.org/):

```
// Produces [{'id':1,'title':'bob'},{etc},{etc}]
var json = JSON.stringify(items);
```

Also keep in mind that $.post() automatically serializes an object data parameter, as key1=value1&key2=value2&etc.  Unless you strictly need JSON on the server-side, the JSON serialization step may not be necessary.

Comment: your map() need a .get() at the end

Answer (score 5):

```
var items = [];

$('ul.nameList').children().each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var item = { id: $this.attr('value'), title: $this.html() };
  items.push(item);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply push these to a **JSON object**, Here is how -

```
   // create a blank array
    var mylist = [];

    // loop trough the li
    $("ul.nameList > li").each(function () {    
    //push element data to the array
        mylist.push({
            "id": $(this).attr("value"),
            "title": $(this).text()
        });
    })

    // then you can simply pass it to the post method 
    $.post("myhandler.php", { list: mylist }, function (data) {
        // recived data
   })
```

And of course the your **html**

```
<ul class="nameList">
    <li value="1">Bob</li>
    <li value="2">Frank</li>
    <li value="3">Sally</li>
</ul>
```

**Working example** - http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadwali/tkhb5/

Hope this helped!