# Restructure a single level UL with links into a nested list based on the link urls

Tags: jquery, json, url, html-lists

I have a single level unordered list with links to various directory levels.
I want to recreate an unordered list from the markup but nesting the list items based on the directory structure of the link URLs.

So changing this example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/folder/page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/folder/page3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

into this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/page1">Page 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/folder/page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/folder/page3">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a jsfiddle work-in-progress which is compiled based on two similar stackoverflow questions, but I can't get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/logopogo/q6H7e/1/

My current line of thought is to convert the single level list into javascript data (JSON ?) using the answer from here:
[How do I convert the items of an LI into a json object using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837383/how-do-i-convert-the-items-of-an-li-into-a-json-object-using-jquery)

Then reconstruct a new list from that JSON data using the answer from here:
[Create a nested UL menu based on the URL path structure of menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133657/create-a-nested-ul-menu-based-on-the-url-path-structure-of-menu-items)