# Get the child li value with its parent ul value in a json using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have an unordered list and some `li` elements under the `ul`. I can not get the `ul` and `li` value as I expect. I tried several resources as below:

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadwali/tkhb5/

[how-do-i-convert-the-items-of-an-li-into-a-json-object-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837383/how-do-i-convert-the-items-of-an-li-into-a-json-object-using-jquery)

[jquery-tree-traversal-nested-unordered-list-elements-to-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172775/jquery-tree-traversal-nested-unordered-list-elements-to-json)

My code is here as below in the fiddle:

[My code is in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkhb5/261/)

My expected output is as below:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "category": "Parking",
    "subcategory": [
        "Street Parking",
        "Bus Parking"
    ]
}]
```

How can I achieve the JSON?

Comment: I researced a lot, But why down vote?

Comment: I did not down-voted, but I suppose apart from adding links if you could add your code snippet here as well question would look more complete. Instead of pasting bunch of links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Please note that I've changed the html a bit by adding a `data-name` to the top `li` elements.

```
var mylist = [];
$(".nameList > li").each(function() {
    mylist.push({});
  var self = mylist[mylist.length-1];
  self.subcategory = [];
  self.id = $(this).attr("value");
  self.category = $(this).attr("data-name");
  $(this).find("ul > li").each(function(){
    self.subcategory.push($(this).html());
  });
  console.log(self);
});
```

And here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkhb5/262/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't touch the HTML, here you have an option...

```
var myList = [];

$('ul.nameList > li').each(function() {
    myList.push({
        "id": $(this).val(),
        "category": $(this).clone().children('ul.subcatList').remove().end().text().trim(),
        "subcategory": $(this).find('ul.subcatList li').toArray().map(function(value) { return value.innerHTML; })
    });
});
```

... but if you can, I will put the category name in some element, to make easier to select it. You could use...

```
<li value="1"><span class="cattitle">Parking</span>
  <ul class="subcatList">
    <li>Street Parking</li>
    <li>Bus Parking</li>
    <li>Complementary Parking</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li value="2"><span class="cattitle">Business Services</span>
  <ul class="subcatList">
    <li>Business Center</li>
    <li>A/V Capabilities</li>
    <li>Video Conferencing</li>
  </ul>
</li>
........
```

... so you can simplify the jQuery...

```
var myList = [];

$('ul.nameList > li').each(function() {
    myList.push({
        "id": $(this).val(),
        "category": $(this).children('span.classtitle').text(),
        "subcategory": $(this).find('ul.subcatList li').toArray().map(function(value) { return value.innerHTML; })
    });
});
```

I hope it helps